# In ZFC, is there a set $X$ such that every strict subset $Y$ of $X$ (i.e. $Y\neq X$) is a member of $X,$ other than the trivial $X=\emptyset$?

Tags: set-theory

I tried to construct such a set: $\{\ 0,\ \{0\},\ \{ \{ 0 \} \},\ \ldots,\ \{ 0,\ \{0\} \}, ? \} $ but I'm not sure it can be done. Can I continue contructing the set by transfinite induction? Or is there a disproof akin to Russel's paradox?

Attempt: If it can be done, then it must be true that, for every $x\in X,\ \{X\setminus x\}\ $ is a member of $X.$ But Russel's paradox says that since $\{X\setminus x\} $ cannot be a member of $\{X\setminus x\},$ this forces $ x = \{X\setminus x\}.\ $ It is not difficult to see that if $X \neq \emptyset,\ $ then $\vert X \vert \geq 2,$ so we may write $\ x_1 = \{ X\setminus \{x_1\} \},\ x_2 = \{ X\setminus \{x_2\} \}.\ $ Therefore, $x_2$ lies inside a set inside $x_1$ and $x_1$ lies inside a set inside $x_2.$ Therefore, $x_2$ lies inside a set inside a set inside a set inside $x_2$. Does Russel's paradox say that this is impossible?

Answer (score 6):

Almost no, because then $\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{X\}\subseteq X$. If $X$ is non-empty, then $\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{X\}$ has size $2^{|X|}-1$.

So we have that $|X|\geq 2^{|X|}-1$, one can easily see that the only two solutions are $|X|=0$ and $|X|=1$, with the latter as $X=\{\varnothing\}$.